# Spring WS : XML Namespace Prefix Handling without package-info.java?

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, xml-namespaces, spring-ws

I have a SOAP service running on Java 1.6 which generates this XML response.
Note the ns5,6,8 in the namespace prefix.

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ns8:getTIR
        xmlns:ns5="urn:name.com:enterprise:schemas:common:elements"
        xmlns:ns6="urn:name.com:dms:schemas:organization"
        xmlns:ns8="urn:name.com:dms:wsdls:organization">
        <getTIR>
            <Attributes>
                <ns6:TargetingAttribute>
                    <ns5:Name>Country</ns5:Name>
                    <ns5:Code>CT</ns5:Code>
                    <ns5:ID>4</ns5:ID>
```

Having migrated the code to spring and Java 8, I get a similar message but the namespace numbering has changed to ns2,3,5.

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ns5:getTIR
        xmlns:ns2="urn:name.com:enterprise:schemas:common:elements"
        xmlns:ns3="urn:name.com:dms:schemas:organization"
        xmlns:ns5="urn:name.com:dms:wsdls:organization">
        <getTIR>
            <Attributes>
                <ns3:TargetingAttribute>
                    <ns2:Name>Country</ns2:Name>
                    <ns2:Code>CT</ns2:Code>
                    <ns2:ID>4</ns2:ID>
```

I need to ensure the namespace numbering is the same.

- I do not have access to the schema or wsdl files, so just updating the 'package-info' is not an option.

In a standard JAXB implementation, I could use a NamespacePrefixMapper to convert the namespaces

```
public class MyNamespaceMapper extends com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper {

    private static final String FOO_PREFIX = "ns5";
    private static final String FOO_URI = "urn:name.com:enterprise:schemas:common:elements";

    private static final String BAR_PREFIX = "ns6";
    private static final String BAR_URI = "urn:name.com:dms:schemas:organization";

    private static final String BAR2_PREFIX = "ns8";
    private static final String BAR2_URI = "urn:name.com:dms:wsdls:organization";

    @Override
    public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean requirePrefix) {
        String reply = suggestion;
        if(FOO_URI.equals(namespaceUri)) {
            reply = FOO_PREFIX;
        } else if(BAR_URI.equals(namespaceUri)) {
            reply = BAR_PREFIX;
        } else if(BAR2_URI.equals(namespaceUri)) {
            reply = BAR2_PREFIX;
        }
        return reply;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getPreDeclaredNamespaceUris() {
        return new String[] { FOO_URI, BAR_URI, BAR2_URI };
    }
}
```

And then inject the 'com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper' property of the javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext like this

```
    JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(GetTargetingInfoResponse.class);
    Marshaller m = ctx.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    try {
        //m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new MyNamespaceMapper());
        m.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new MyNamespaceMapper());
    } catch(PropertyException e) {
        // In case another JAXB implementation is used
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    m.marshal(root, System.out);
```

With Spring WS - I've defined this config where is create my own custom 'org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller' bean,
passing the same JABX properties

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableWs
public class AppWebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter defaultMethodEndpointAdapter() {
        List<MethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers =
                new ArrayList<MethodArgumentResolver>();
        argumentResolvers.add(getMarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor());

        List<MethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers =
                new ArrayList<MethodReturnValueHandler>();
        returnValueHandlers.add(getMarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor());

        DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter adapter = new DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter();
        adapter.setMethodArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
        adapter.setMethodReturnValueHandlers(returnValueHandlers);

        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor getMarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor() {
        log.info("getMarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor()");
        return new MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor(createJaxb2Marshaller());
    }

    @Bean
    public MyNamespaceMapper getMyNamespaceMapper() {
        return new MyNamespaceMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller createJaxb2Marshaller() {
        org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setSupportJaxbElementClass(true);
        marshaller.setContextPaths("....");
        Map marshallerProps = new HashMap();
        marshallerProps.put("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", getTargetingInfoNamespaceMapper());
        //marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(marshallerProps);
        marshaller.setJaxbContextProperties(marshallerProps);
        return marshaller;
    }
}
```

but my app fails with this exception.

```
org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper" is not supported- with linked exception:
    [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper" is not supported]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:955)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:514)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:480)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Spring Versions

```
<spring.boot.version>2.2.13.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<spring.framework.version>5.2.12.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
```

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: nope, :-(.......